# Amazon Athena - insert Query error "[Simba][JDBC](10940) Invalid parameter index: 1."

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-athena

I have been trying to export from my machine to Athena DB using a prepared statement. Query given

```
"INSERT INTO "default"."bjhfhj" VALUES ('?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?','?')"
```

Code:

```
preparedStatement= dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertQuery.toString());
preparedStatement.setString(1, "<colValue>");
```

For this piece of code, I'm getting the error `"[Simba][JDBC](10940) Invalid parameter index: 1."`

Stack trace :

```
com.simba.athena.exceptions.ExceptionConverter.toSQLException(Unknown Source)
com.simba.athena.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.checkValidParameterIndex(Unknown Source)
com.simba.athena.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.setString(Unknown Source)
```

exact java code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class AmazonAthena {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connection_URL = "jdbc:awsathena://athena.<AWSREGION>.amazonaws.com:443;User=<ACCESS_KEY>;Password=<SECRET_KEY>;S3OutputLocation=<S3_OUTPUT_LOCATION>;";
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connection_URL);
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement= connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO \"dataprepdb\".\"bjhfhj\" VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            String value = "dhv";
            for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
                preparedStatement.setString(i+1,value+i);
            }
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.printf("error");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Your SQL is wrong. The ? is a placeholder, don't use ' ' parcel.

This is correct:

```
"INSERT INTO default.bjhfhj VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

You should know how to use a placeholder for preparedStatement.

====

Try this:

1. Modify the sql like this to insert only one field, and make sure that the insterted value is of the type required by the field.

   "insert into t_user (id) values (?)"
2. Use this method to set value

   query.setParameter(0, someVarId);

And if that doesn't work,I can't help you also.I am sorry.

Comment: I have tried using this also but didn't make any difference both the format throws same error only. @RedSnack-BCS, I have been using other sql's too with this ""INSERT INTO default.bjhfhj VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"" format but it's not working for amazon athena.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's not working in my case.